# react-redux with infinite scroll

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm using react-infinite-scroll-component to build a infinite scroll based on data returned from the store.
I'm using react-redux:

```
<InfiniteScroll
  dataLength={items.length}
  next={fetchData}
  hasMore={true}>
   {this.state.items.map((i, index) => (
      <div style={style} key={index}>
         div - #{index}
      </div>
    ))}
</InfiniteScroll>
```

fetchData:

```
fetchMoreData = () => {
   let { actions } = this.props;
    actions.getMoreItems();
};
```

But this call : `actions.getMoreItems();`
Makes a infinite loop call
How can I call an action from store without make the loop call ?
Thanks.